# How to use structs array to make a list of players?

Tags: c, struct

I'm new to structs. I'm making a program in which I wanna build a list of players with structs . This is what I wrote 'til now. It's in Italian. But basically the program works fine when I insert just one player. It doesn't when I want to add more than one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 25

struct rol{
    int position[3];
    int lato[1];
};
typedef struct rol role;

struct pl{
    role *ruol;
    int shirt_num;
    char name[20];
    char lastn[20];
};
typedef struct pl player;

struct tm{
    int classpos;
    int pnt;
    player players[MAX];
};


typedef struct tm team;

void define_role (role *ruolo);
void make_pl(player *pl);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int risp;
    player *giocatore;
    int cont;
    printf("Vuoi effettuare lavori su un giocatore o su una squadra ? \n [ 1) giocatore  2)  squadra] ");
    scanf("%d",&risp);
    if(risp==1){
    printf("\n\n1)Crea Giocatore \n 2)Modifica giocatore \n3)Inserisci giocatore in una squadra");
    printf("\n 4)Visualizza dati giocatore \n ");
    scanf("%d",&risp);
    if(risp==1){
        cont++;

    giocatore = (player*)malloc (cont*sizeof(player));
    make_pl(&giocatore[cont-1]); //this is the main problem basically 
    }
    }
    return 0;
}

void make_pl(player *pl){
    printf("\n Inserisci nome ");
    scanf("%s",pl->name);
    printf("\n Inserisci cognome ");
    scanf("%s",pl->lastn);
    define_role(pl->ruol);
    printf("Inserisci numero di maglia ");
    scanf("%d",&pl->shirt_num);
    } 

void define_role(role *ruolo){
    printf("\n Inserisci lato ");
    scanf("%d",&ruolo->lato);
    printf("\n Inserisci posizione ");
    scanf("%d",&ruolo->position);

    }
```

I ran with the constant cont =1 and it works for obvious reasons. When I upgrade the value because I want add a new player when it gets into the function define role it blocks after the first scanf.

```
scanf("%d",&ruolo->lato);
```

and it says exit error bla bla bla.

I just want to make a list of players with their technical features. I don't know what's the problem. When I build it gave me no errors.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `int main(int argc, char** argv) {`  The parameters `argc` and `argv` are not used.  This causes the compiler to output 2 warning messages.  Suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`  I.E.  `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d",&ruolo->lato);`   (remember that a bare array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array) causes the compiler to output a warning: "untitled2.c:64:13: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)[1]’ [-Wformat=]".   This due to the extranious `&`  Suggest `scanf( "%d", ruolo->lato );`  Notice no `&`.  Similar considerations exist for: `scanf("%d",&ruolo->position);`

Comment: that is the basic initialization of netbeans. That aint the problem all my codes contain that part and they all worked before .

Comment: i tried to delete the "&" it still gives me the same issue
 Inserisci nome Bobby

 Inserisci cognome Solo

 Inserisci lato 2

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 28s)

Comment: regarding: `int cont;` and `if(risp==1){
        cont++;`  results in the compiler message:  "untitled2.c:43:13: warning: ‘cont’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]"  This needs to be fixed.  Suggest:  `int cont = 0;`  so the variable is initialized before being used

Comment: i tried with cont=0 it still exit after the command " scanf( "%d", ruolo->lato )"

Comment: since the variable: `cont` is not initialized to a known value, this statement: `giocatore = (player*)malloc (cont*sizeof(player));` contains undefined behavior.  Also, in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer, so the cast just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.   Also, when calling: `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: main.cpp:46:24: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'player* {aka pl*}' [-fpermissive]
     giocatore = malloc (cont*sizeof(player));
this is what says if i delete (player*)

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding, by us humans, (the compiler doesn't care) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace.  Unindent before every closing brace.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: regarding: `main.cpp`   this is claiming that the code is C++, not C.  so either rename to `main.c` or change the question tag from 'c' to 'c++'

Comment: no it is supposed to be a C program tbh .

Comment: If it is supposed to be a C program, then stop misdirecting the compiler into thinking it is C++.  This is done by changing the extension from `.cpp`  to `.c`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%s",pl->name);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  For the current statement, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  2) when using the 'input format conversion specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a max characters modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also assures that no buffer overflow occurs with its' attendant undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `if(risp==1)`  so when the `risp` is not 1, the program exits

Comment: OT:  regarding: `struct tm`   This is a well known name for a structure that contains 'time' information.  It is a poor programming practice to redefine well known structure definitions.  Suggest: `struct team`

Comment: regarding: `struct pl{
    role *ruol;`  and the function: `define_role()`   That function is accessing offsets into where `ruol` points, but that pointer has never been set to point to memory that the program owns.  Suggest:  ``struct pl{
    role ruol;`  Notice no `*`.   After fixing this problem, there are a couple of other statements in the program that will need to be updated

Comment: regarding: `struct rol{
    int position[3];`   This is declaring any array of 3 integers, but the posted code is only setting the first integer.

Comment: The posted code contains a memory leak!  It allocates dynamic memory for the variable:  `player *giocatore;` but fails to release that allocated memory by calling: `free( giocatore );` before exiting the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and i found some issues, when you use `scanf()` this function read every character from the input until it found a white-space but doesn't read the line-break, so, you need to clean the input or just put a white-space before the formatting string: `scanf(" %d", &somVariable);`. You need to assign memory to the structure `role` which is inside of the structure `player`, so in your function `define_role` there won't a segmentation fault, also you need to add a value to your ```cont``variable. I put the code with this corrections and i added a while to add more players.

**EDITED**

I read your comment, i didn't notice that `make_pl(&giocatore[cont-1]);` you treat `gicatore` as an array but it's a pointer of player structure, so when you try to add a second player the program ends with an error. So the solution is create an array, or a linked list, to save the player that you add. The main problem with the array is that you can add only a specific number of players if you try to pass that limit the program will end with an error, so i recommend you use a linked list.

I set `scanf("%d",&ruolo->lato[index])` in 0 because lato is an array of one int in your struct role, you could declare a int instead an array of only one int, so to acces the first element of an array you need to set the index in 0, if you write, for example, 120 this number it will save in lato[0]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 25

struct rol{
    int position[3];
    int lato[1];
};
typedef struct rol role;

struct pl{
    role *ruol;
    int shirt_num;
    char name[20];
    char lastn[20];
};
typedef struct pl player;

struct tm{
    int classpos;
    int pnt;
    player players[MAX];
};


typedef struct tm team;

void define_role (role *ruolo);
void make_pl(player *pl);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int risp;
    player *giocatore;
    player players[MAX];
    int cont = 0;
    printf("Vuoi effettuare lavori su un giocatore o su una squadra ? \n [ 1) giocatore  2)  squadra] ");
    scanf(" %d",&risp);

    if(risp==1) {
        do {
            printf("\n\n1)Crea Giocatore\n2)Modifica giocatore\n3)Inserisci giocatore in una squadra");
            printf("\n4)Visualizza dati giocatore\n 5) Finish program\n");
            scanf(" %d",&risp);
            if(risp==1) {
                cont++;
                giocatore = (player*)malloc (cont*sizeof(player));
                giocatore->ruol = (role*)malloc(sizeof(role));
                make_pl(giocatore); //this is the main problem basically 
                players[cont-1] = *giocatore;
            }
        } while(risp != 5);
    }
    return 0;
}

void make_pl(player *pl) {
    printf("\n Inserisci nome ");
    scanf(" %s",pl->name);
    printf("\n Inserisci cognome ");
    scanf(" %s",pl->lastn);
    define_role(pl->ruol);
    printf("Inserisci numero di maglia ");
    scanf(" %d",&pl->shirt_num);
} 

void define_role(role *ruolo) {
    printf("\n Inserisci lato ");
    scanf(" %d",&ruolo->lato[0]);
    printf("\n Inserisci posizione ");
    scanf(" %d",&ruolo->position[0]);
}
```

Comment: regarding your statement: `scanf(" %d", $somVariable);`  Most of the input format conversion specifiers consume 'white space', including `%d` so no need for a leading space in the format string.  BTW: what is that leading `$`?

Comment: @Maverik your modified code works well if i insert the first player but when it asks me if i wanna add a new player it gives me the same problem . after the command " scanf("%d",&ruolo->lato) " the program exit.

Comment: also what's the use of scanf("%d",&ruolo->lato[index]) and why you set it up at 0